# sum of str and float number by using the type function not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print out the sum of str and float number by using the type function but somehow it's not working

```
var1,var2,var3=[str(2),float(3.0),str(5)]
print([var1,var2,var3])
```

if I simply apply plus function `print(var1+var2+var3)` it gives an error which I don't understand

> TypeError: must be str, not float

Comment: Do you want to print out the **sum** of the numbers?

Comment: yes, I want to print out the sum of the numbers

Comment: And what does the error message look like? Please add it to your question.

Comment: You cannot add strings with integer. That's why you're getting TypeError.

Comment: Another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583409/python-typeerror-must-be-str-not-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write:

```
print(sum(float(i) for i in [var1,var2,var3]))
```

But instead you can easily use it as below:

```
values = [str(2),float(3.0),str(5)]
```

in case the types are not matching you need to convert it to same type and then add it so you can do in one line by list comprehension as below:

```
float_values = [float(i) for i in values]  # list of all values as float
print(sum(float_values))
```

---

**+ operator**

when you use strings with `+` operator it will concatenate strings

Ex.

```
x = '4' + '5'  # result will be '45'
```

If you use it for integer it will give you addition of values 
Ex.

```
x = 4 + 5  # result will be 9
```

Comment: Really thanks a lot ..I am totally new to python that's why it's taking time for me to understand the basis @Gahan